# Jquery Templates - append table rows inside table element and clear any existing rows first

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I have a template that looks like this:

```
<div id="PopUpTemplate" style="display: none">
    <tr><td>${Key}</td><td>${Value}</td></tr>
</div>
```

and I want to append it into a table :

```
<div id="MessageBox">
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

and then use Jquery UI dialog to display that as a popup, which I'm doing like this:

```
$('#PopUpTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo("#MessageBox table");


        $('#MessageBox').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            buttons: { 'Ok': function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
            position: 'center'
        });
```

I have 2 problems:

The first is that the template gets appended after the closing `</table>` tag

The second is that when I call this multiple times, I get more data added into the table. But I want to clear all the existing rows first, then append the new set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty new to this but after messing around with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbhRm/3/), I think you may be doing the templating wrong. The template if stored on your page is going to get cleaned by most browsers as it is not valid html, for the instance of chrome the tr/td tags are stripped, your template then becomes a single div. This div is then inserted correctly and likely cleaned up by your browser and put after the table as it makes no sense to insert as a row (because it is not).

As for replacing the current rows, once you get your template working as a template you can simply use `.html` on your `#MessageBox table` selector replacing any current rows instead of using `appendTo`.

All that being said, without seeing more context I can't be totally sure this has answered your question. Perhaps create a fiddle so we can see exactly what is going on.

Comment: After learning a bit more about this if you use `<script type='text/template'>` you should not run into these type of problem